# Redesign radiobuttons

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I want to create custom design for radiobuttons on my website. Unfortunately I got stuck in the very beginning. I need to put image of my custom radiobutton after each radiobutton. I also need to assign them id based on radiobutton's id (so I can later handle checking/unchecking). Here's my code:

```
var radio = $('<img class="radiobutton" src="/images/radiobutton.png" alt="radiobutton" />');
$('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    radio.attr('id', id + '-image');
    $(this).after(radio);
});
```

This results into just one image after the last radiobutton instead of all of them... I have no idea what's wrong with that code.

Comment: try to create a fiddle , it will help you

Comment: radio is a single HTML element which you are creating outside of the loop, modifying, then moving around each run through the loop.  You need to move the line where you create radio inside of your loop so you get a new element each time.

Comment: thanx man, sometimes I'm just stupid and don't see the easy things. Putting declaration of radio into the loop did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this edit to your code :

```
var radio = $('<img class="radiobutton" src="/images/radiobutton.png" alt="radiobutton" />');
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(index , value) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    radio[index].attr('id', id + '-image');
    $(this).after(radio);
});
```

Comment: This code presumed that the imgs following the radio button are already present in the DOM.  I believe OP is inserting the imgs in his above code, so $('img.radiobutton') is going to return an empty list.